# PHP - Creating an array with explode

Tags: php, sorting, explode

My php problem is following:

I have this string: `$days="Monday* Tuesday* Wednesday*"`

I want to create an array like this: `$d[1]="Monday"; $d[2]="Tuesday"; $d[3]="Wednesday"`

I sense that the solution passes by `explode(*, $days)` but I couldn't get further

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: how about dealing to the source of the $days string to make this easer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$days="Monday* Tuesday* Wednesday*";
$d=explode('* ', $days);
```

or

```
$days="Monday* Tuesday* Wednesday*";
$d=explode(' ', str_replace('*','',$days));
```

for exclude "*" in end of last word.

Answer (score 1):

```php
explode('* ', trim($days, '*'));
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use :

```
explode("* ", $days)
```

But IMO, I would use a coma like this :

```
$days  = "Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday";
$days = explode(",", $days);
echo $days[0]; // => Monday
echo $days[1]; // => Tuesday
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$days="Monday* Tuesday* Wednesday*";
$exploded = explode('* ',substr($days, 0, -1));
print_r($exploded);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Monday
    [1] => Tuesday
    [2] => Wednesday
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$days = 'Monday* Tuesday* Wednesday*';
$d = array_filter(explode('* ', $days));
```